# How to call a certain number of requests in a certain period of time in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to call a certain API 20000 times in 30 minutes in jmeter.
Now I'm setting up a certain number of threads, considering how long this API takes to respond to me, and as a result I get about 20000 requests in 30 minutes.
But the problem is that the number of API requests is always different, for example 18000 or 24000 requests.
Is it possible to set up jmeter so that the API is called exactly the number of times in a certain time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches like:

- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3Fr.jpg
- [Throughout Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITaO.jpg
- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3dHG.jpg

If you want to run not more than 20000 requests you can limit it via [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3A1P.jpg